# Android Not Sure How To Refer To Value In JSON File (JSON Parsing)

Tags: android, android-location, arrays, json

Example JSON Page
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=51.155455,-0.165058&sensor=true

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void readAndParseJSON(String in) {
    try {
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(in);
        // This works and returns address
        JSONArray resultArry = reader.getJSONArray("results");
        String Address = resultArry.getJSONObject(1).getString("formatted_address").toString();
        Log.e("Address", Address);
        // Trying to get PostCode on code below - this is not working (log says no value at address components)
        JSONArray postCodeArray  = reader.getJSONArray("address_components");
        String postCode =  postCodeArray.getJSONObject(1).getString("long_name").toString();
        Log.e("PostCode", postCode );
```

This code returns the address correctly. How can I get the post code long_name which is inside address_components?

**Solution**
I had to get each array, and then get the post code value.
I am using the value 7, as that is the JSONObject that has the postcode stored in the "long_name" field.

```
JSONObject readerJsonObject = new JSONObject(in);
 readerJsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
 JSONArray resultsJsonArray = readerJsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
 JSONArray postCodeJsonArray = resultsJsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("address_components");
 String postCodeString =  postCodeJsonArray.getJSONObject(7).getString("long_name").toString();         
 Log.e("TAG", postCodeString);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
reader.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("address_components");
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I solved this problem. Please see my answer for an update.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `results` is a `JSONArray` that contains a child `JSONObject` composed of several children: `"address_components"`, `"formatted_address"`, `"geometry"`, and `"types"`. The `result` array actually contains many of these such objects, but let's focus on just the first child for now.

Look carefully at your code. With this line:

```
JSONArray resultArry = reader.getJSONArray("results");
```

You are getting the entire `results`. Later on, you then call the same method again:

```
JSONArray postCodeArray  = reader.getJSONArray("address_components");
```

But you're asking for an `"address_components"` from the reader, where I do not expect you'll find anything (having already read the entire result before.) You should instead be working with the `JSONArray` you already got before, since it already contains the entire result.

Try something like:

```
JSONObject addressComponents = resultArry.getJSONObject(1).getJSONObject("address_components");
String postCode = addressComponents.getString("long_name");
```

Note: I don't know why you're singling out JSONObject #1 (as opposed to 0, which is the first, or any other one of them) and I also am not sure why you named the String postCode. So if I've misunderstood your intention, I apologize.

Comment: Hi, I singled out JsonObject 1 as It returned the address in the format I want it.

I named the string postCode as I am trying to save just the postcode part from the JSON.

The address part works and I get the address back from the JSON file,
I am just trying to get postcode separately to store into postCode String.

Comment: I tried your code and I get the error
at address_components of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)

Comment: Yup, looks like you eventually got it. JSON is tricky with []'s and {}'s and I seem to always get them mixed up too.

Answer (score 0):

Is difficult to find the error... because all looks well. The problem maybe can exist when you make the json.put("address_components", something);

So my advice is put a breakpoint at this line

```
 JSONArray postCodeArray  = reader.getJSONArray("address_components");
```

o display the json in logcat

```
Log.d("Simple", reader.toString());
```

Then Paste your json in this web page to view more pretty

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

and check if all keys are stored well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I solved it, please see my answer for an update.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
Need to get each array, and then get the post code value. The value 7 is used, as that is the JSONObject that has the postcode stored in the "long_name" field.

```
JSONObject readerJsonObject = new JSONObject(in);
 readerJsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
 JSONArray resultsJsonArray = readerJsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
 JSONArray postCodeJsonArray = resultsJsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("address_components");
 String postCodeString =  postCodeJsonArray.getJSONObject(7).getString("long_name").toString();         
 Log.e("TAG", postCodeString);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: if this is the solution, you should mark it as the answer so that it's clear for everyone that follows.